# Why can't boost::bind deduce the return type when binding the constructor<> functor?

Tags: c++, boost, constructor, lambda, bind

... in spite of the fact that the library-supplied `constructor<>` functor adapter defines the `sig<>` template?

```
struct Porc
{
    Porc(int x) {}
};

boost::bind
(
    boost::lambda::constructor<Porc>(),
    _1
)(1);
```

error: no type named ‘result_type’ in ‘struct boost::lambda::constructor’

What I am trying to do is create a functor that takes an int and creates & returns a Porc object using that int.
Note: If I explicitly specify the return type of the functor (which is Porc), like below, it works:

```
boost::bind<Porc>
(
    boost::lambda::constructor<Porc>(),
    _1
)(1);
```

I'm relatively new to lambda expressions but I think/hope I got the basics. It says [here in the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.bind_expressions) that **In general, BLL cannot deduce the return type of an arbitrary function object. However, there are two methods for giving BLL this capability for a certain function object class. [...] The result_type typedef and [...] The sig template**. Since the `constructor<>` is library provided, of course they declared a `sig<>` template.

Comment: Have you tried `boost::lambda::bind`?

Comment: To echo @David, why would you think that `boost::bind` would know anything about the Boost.Lambda library? (And FWIW, Boost.Lambda is dead, use [Boost.Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/libs/phoenix/) instead.)

Comment: You are right, I was mixing boost::bind with boost::lambda::bind. I see that lambda library accommodates functors that define result_type (such as those in the STL and boost::bind), but boost::bind and other libraries don't understand the `sig` thing. I'm referring here to boost::range iterator adapters such as `transform`, which also requires return_type. In the end it was simpler for me to ditch the lambda and use just boost::bind, together with `boost::value_factory<>` as an alternative to `boost::lambda::constructor<>.`

Comment: and why do you say boost::lambda is 'dead'? I didnt find that info elsewhere - except that they are very similar and will be merged at some point?

Comment: @haelix : See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10842037/636019) and its comments for details.